# Approximation of conditional expectation of unknown function

Tags: regression, approximation-theory

I am given a multidimensional markovian stochastic process $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ with continuous state space and  unknown to me function $V$. I want to approximate expectation 
$E(V(X_k)|X_{k-1} = x)$ which is a function of $x$.

Suppose that I can simulate the entire sequence  $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ using Monte Carlo. And for each $X_{k-1}^i$ from the black box I am given the value of $V(X_k^i)$ where $i$ denotes simulation index.

I understand that my question is too general, I hope that you will give me some references for this topic.

Comment: As stated, the problem is too general. It all depends on the numbers $X_i$ and $Y_i$ and what you are going to do with the approximation. After all, polynomial interpolation can fit your data exactly if you use high enough degree. If the data appears approximately periodic, then using finite Fourier series is appropriate.

Comment: @Somos, thanks for your comment. Yes, I understand that my question is too broad, but could you recommend me some sources where I can get general understanding of this kind of problems?

Comment: How about [Curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)?

Comment: This problem arises in the valuation/pricing of American options by Monte Carlo methods. In addition to the suggestions by Somos google "Least Squares Monte Carlo".

Comment: @gg, yes but where can I learn mathematical foundations of  Least Squares Monte Carlo? Does mastering this topic require learning some functional analysis, SDEs, theorie of conditional expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem can be approached by "curve fitting" or "least squares Monte Carlo". Both are basically just two names for the same thing: [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) regression. The approach is straightforward and just requires a basic understanding of [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis). So no SDEs, functional analysis or measure theoretic conditional expectation is required.

### The setting

To recognize how and why regression can be applied set $x_i = X_{k-1}^i$ and $y_i=V(X_k^i)$. With this terminology your simulation gives you iid pairs $(x_i,y_i)$. You know that $E[V|X_{k-1}=x_i]$ is a function $f(x_i)$ but you cannot observe this function you only observe a (crude) estimate $y_i$. Call $e_i = y_i -f(x_i)$ the error of the estimate. Notice that

1. $y_i = f(x_i) + e_i$ by definition.
2. The $e_i$ are independent, since you sample each path independent.
3. $E[e_i|X_{i-1}] = E[y_i - f(x_i)|X_{i-1}] = E[y_i | X_{i-1}] - f(x_i) = 0.$

Now make the assumption that the error $e_i$ has a normal distribution and you are in the regression setting.

### Will it work? It depends ...

How successful this will be depends. You need to "guess" the structure of $f$. A standard (initial) guess is assuming $f(x)=\sum \beta_j p_j(x)$ where $p_j(x)$ are polynomials. You choose the $\beta_j$ such that they minimise the quadratic error with your observations, i.e. $\hat\beta = \text{argmin} \sum_i(y_i - \sum \beta_j p_j(x_i))^2$.

Depending on the structure of $f$ other low dimensional families might be better. For example if you know that $f$ is piecewise linear, you would choose piecewise linear functions for the approximation. If $f$ is periodic, use periodic ones and so on.

Another important issue is how fine you can sample $X_{k-1}$. If $f$ is very irregular (i.e. wiggles a lot) and you have only few samples, you are in trouble. Then the variance of $e_i$ will be large and samples with adjacent $x_i$ will be far apart and provide only very little information. If $f$ is more or less linear you only need few samples and linear maybe quadratic polynomials.

There is a rich literature and many tools available to do regression and to analyse the results. Specifically for the pricing of American options have a look at this [review](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Ekohler/preprint09_02.pdf)

Finally you should try to incorporate as much prior information as possible into your approximation. I mentioned already the structure of $f$ and explained the problem for a single location $k$. But if the $V$ functions at different $k$ have a known relation, there are ways to incorporate this as well. But to have a reasonable discussion about this, you need to provide a more detailed specification of your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am very intersted in the last paragraph you wrote about relations between $V$ at different $k$. In the case of American options, I think functions $V$ do have some relation since in my opinion $V$ is combination of inner value of an option and time left before expiry. Could you please provide some references where some assumptions are made on the structure of V and this information is used in the regression?

Comment: So you do American options, do you? See my edit with a review paper and have a look at this reference [imposing structure](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2053755) as an example. That said, "functions $V$ do have some relation" is nothing useful (yet). The stochastic control problems in pricing American options are subtle and you have not even specified what kind of problem you are interested in. I suggest 1) Start to read on the method and implement your own (plain-vanilla) version 2) learn from this and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Few complements to g g's proposition:

So your function $V$ is unknown, but despite this lack of information, you
are able to simulate $V(X_{k}^{i})$ for $X_{k-1}=X_{k-1}^{i}$. In this case,
for a given value of $X_{k-1}^{i}$ why not generating $S$ values $\left\{
V(X_{k}^{s})\right\} _{s=1}^{S}$ and then applying the law of large numbers
to find 
$$ S^{-1}\sum_{s=1}^{S}V(X_{k}^{s})\overset{p}{\rightarrow }E\left[
V(X_{k})|X_{k-1}=X_{k-1}^{i}\right] . $$
Then iterating over $i$ and $k$, this should identify the whole function $E(V(X_k)|X_{k-1} = x).$
There is a literature on simulated least squares that could be helpful.

Comment: Very pertinent remark! Although in practice the computational effort for this kind of approach is often prohibitive. This phenomenon is called "stochastics in stochastics" or "nested simulation". In many cases a compromise is struck: Simulate a few conditional samples, thus reducing the variance of the estimate for $E[V|X_{k-1}]$ and then apply regression.